# What would be the equivalent of Pythons "pickle" in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, amqp

One of Python's features is the **pickle** function, that allows you to store any arbitrary anything, and restore it exactly to its original form. One common usage is to take a fully instantiated object and pickle it for later use. In my case I have an AMQP Message object that is not serializable and I want to be able to store it in a session store and retrieve it which I can do with pickle. The primary difference is that I need to call a **method** on the object, I am not just looking for the data.

But this project is in nodejs and it seems like with all of node's low-level libraries there must be some way to save this object, so that it could persist between web calls.

The use case is that a web page picks up a RabbitMQ message and displays the info derived from it. I don't want to acknowledge the message until the message has been acted on. I would just normally just save the data in session state, but that's not an option unless I can somehow save it in its original form.

Comment: What is "an AMQP Message object"? Why is it not serializable? Serialization sounds like one of the primary things you'd expect to be able to do with anything that you can call a "message" - how are you supposed to send it, otherwise?

Comment: @Karl This is not the actual message but the class for handling the message. AFAIK, functions are not serializable in most formats, only data. Since I want to call the .acknowledge() method on the object at a later point, that is why I want to store it.

Comment: Storing object instances is actually fragile, since you still need the original source code, in its original place in a package hierarchy, to reconstruct it. Better to just pickle data. For Node, json seems a natural choice.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this question was downvoted twice and done so without comment. How do you expect someone to improve questions if you downvote without telling them why?

Comment: I don't know why this question would be downvoted. It's clear, concise, and relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there isn't an equivalent to pickle in JavaScript (or in the standard node libraries).

Answer (score 6):

See the pickle-js project: https://code.google.com/p/pickle-js/

Also, from findbestopensource.com:

> pickle.js is a JavaScript implementation of the Python pickle format. It supports pickles containing a cross-language subset of the primitive types. Key differences between pickle.js and pickle.py:text pickles only some types are lossily converted (e.g. int) some types are not supported (e.g. class)

More information available here: http://www.findbestopensource.com/product/pickle-js

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/carlos8f/hydration to see if it fits your needs. I'm not sure it's as complete as `pickle` but it's pretty terrific.

Disclaimer: The module author and I are coworkers.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately the type that is important for me is "function" which I don't think your project does. Which is a pretty odd use case I will admit.

Comment: It's funny you mention that... maybe a year ago I wrote a small utility to serialize/store/hydrate functions in JS, I'll try to dig it up. Didn't put it on github thinking "who else is ever going to want to hydrate functions??"

Comment: Here, updated and uploaded - definitely not a Pickle replacement, but it does handle functions: https://github.com/hunterloftis/cryo

Comment: @hunterloftis That is **very** cool. That will definitely come in handy on many projects. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! Cryo is great 